# How to loop through WCF using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

This is all a bit black magic to me but I've created a WCF service from an online tutorial which is display some SQL data (running the ASP.NET solution locally produces results from the service so I presume that it's running correctly).

What I'm trying to do is connect to this service from a html page, this is the script that I've created.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    // Send an AJAX request
    alert("running");

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:15021/Service1.svc/getAllCustomers",
    dataType: "json",
    success: alert("Success"),
    error: alert("Failure")
    });

});


</script>
```

I get no errors but I just get 2 alerts (the success and failure), so my question is this how would I actually start to work with the data that the WCF is returning?

Any advice would be great.

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(response){
  //Do the things you want to do with the response data you are getting.
  //And yes you are getting json response, if not there will be errors
}
failure: function(x,e){
  //Do the things you want to do in case of failure.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do something with the data that is returned if any is being returned at all. Try adding some sort of call back function to the success: setting like:

```
function (msg) {
     if (msg !== null) {
     alert(msg);
}
```

and another function to the error: setting so you can see what error you are getting:

```
function (msg) {
    alert(msg.status + " " + msg.statusText);
}
```

Comment: Hi, cheers to both. Apparently it's not working correctly because entering: success: function(response){alert("success")},
  error: function(response){alert("failure")}

Now shows me the error alert only and looking at the resources tab in Chrome it highlights

XMLHTTPRequest cannot load http://localhost:15021/Service1.svc/getAllCustomers. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

I'm running Chrome with --allow-file-access-from-files tagged to the exe (which I thought it might be) but alas! Now I'm really struggling!

Comment: Try to debug and go inside Jquery, if the response you are getting from your WCF is not in JSON format, you will get invalid JSON eror handled inside JQuery implementation. I have the same code writtend for my ajax call and it is working.

Comment: Also, you should try error: function(response){alert(response)} instead of error: function(response){alert("failure")}, and debug what data is in your response, status, and statusText properties have the error info usually.

Comment: Hi,

Putting error: `code` function(response){alert(response.status + " " + response.statusText)} 

into the error handler returns 0 Error on the alert

tres confused!

Comment: To be honest boys and girls I think that I need to go away and do some more research into this. Think I'm dealing with black magic!